# Passing escaped quotes as a parameter in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script with user input like so:

```
echo -n "Enter string for Read Group parameter: "
read readgroup
```

I am passing this variable to another application that requires this parameter to be a string that starts with @ and is enclosed in quotes on the command line.

This is the correct command-line syntax:

```
application -R '@text'
application -R "@text"
```

These commands would produce errors if run on command line:

```
application -R @text
application -R "text"
application -R 'text'
```

In my script, I have tried putting escaped quotes in the passed variable:

```
echo $readgroup
'@text'
application -R "$readgroup"    # error: does not start with @
```

Or passing it without the quotes:

```
echo $readgroup
@text
application -R "$readgroup"   # error: no parameter entry recognized
application -R \""$readgroup"\"   # error: does not start with @
application -R "'"'$readgroup'"'"   # error: does not start with @
```

And tried other solutions from stackoverflow like arrays:

```
readgroup=("@text")
application -R "${readgroup[@]}"   # error: does not start with @
```

The problem is that when I include the quotes in the original variable or escape the quotes on the command call, the application interprets it as a literal string (e.g. beginning with a quote and therefore invalid, since it must begin with an @).  However when I don't include the quotes, it returns an error because there are no quotes for the application call.

Is there a way to force the shell to interpret the escaped quotes (in the script) as actual command line quotes (parameters) or to add those quotes explicitly in the application call in the script?

Or is a different approach considered better, such as using arguments for the script instead?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks strange to me.  What console (command-line) and shell are you using to issue the application command?  For a bash shell, an argument with quote `"@text"` should be the same as without quote `@text`.  The bash simply do some transformation inside the double quotes, and remove the double quotes.  (Transformation: variable substitution, etc..).  Since @text has no special meaning to bash shell, the double quotes are just removed without any transformation.

Comment: I mean, it seems to be a contradiction that you said  `application -R "@text"` works, but `application -R @text` not.

Comment: Does `\"@test\"` work for you?

Comment: It sounds like the application is asking for `"@<string>"` as the input. As in, the application requires the string to start and end with `'"'` character?

Comment: Try `set -x` to see how they are different (as mentioned, there's no reason)

Comment: @bentank this is correct; I think it is an application requirement that that particular parameter requires some form of quote on the command-line input, otherwise it won't recognize the string.  For more information, the application I'm referring to is the popular short-read aligner BWAmem -- a bioinformatics tool.  It might be that the problem is coming from the way their application handles the input.  Thanks for all the comments, I will give them a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application environment is not specified here, can you elaborate more about your application and its environment.

Also did you tried        `application -R "@$readgroup"`

Comment: My shell is bash.  For whatever reason though, your suggestion worked.

For others using BWAmem with the Read Group field, the string entered was (example):  `RG\\tID:group\\tSM:sample1\\tPL:illumina\\tLB:lib1\\tPU:unit1`

And the call to the application was as Amit suggested:

`application -R "@$readgroup"`

Thanks!

Comment: If it is bash, than surely suggestion will work. Also if this solved your problem, plz accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `eval "application -R '$readgroup'"` would do literally the same as you wrote in correct command line sytax, since it gets the whole command as a string.

On the other hand there might be something tricky going on. I think inside `application` it can't be decided if `$readgroup` was specified with or without quotes. At last the `main()` will only get unquoted `char *argv[]`!